# How to append a value in excel based on cell values from multiple columns in Python and/or R

Tags: python, r, excel, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm new to the openpyxl and other similar excel packages in Python (even Pandas). **What I want to achieve is to append the lowest possible price that I can keep for each of the product based on the expense formula.** The expense formula is in the code below, the data is like this on excel:

```
**Product** |**Cost** |**Price** |  **Lowest_Price**
ABC            32          66   
XYZ            15          32   
DEF            22          44   
JML            60          120
```

I have the code below code on Python 3.5, which works, however this might not be the most optimized solution, I need to know how to append the lowest value on Lowest_price column:

```
cost = 32 #Cost of product from cost column
price = 66 #Price of product from price column
Net = cost+5 #minimum profit required
lowest = 0 #lowest price that I can keep on the website for each product

#iterating over each row values and posting the lowest value adjacent to each product. 

for i in range(Net, price):
    expense = (i*0.15) + 15 #expense formula
    if i - expense >= Net:
        lowest = i
        break
print (lowest)  #this value should be printed adjacent to the price, in the Lowest price Column
```

#### Now if someone can help me doing that in Python and/or R. The reason I want in both Python and R is because I want to compare the time complexity, as I have a huge set of data to deal with.

*I'm fine with code that works with any of the excel formats i.e. xls or xlsx as long it is fast*

Comment: have you looked at pandas dataframes in python?

Comment: @Usernamenotfound I have not, could you please give me an example of doing that in pandas

Comment: How frequently will you have to update data in the spreadsheet? Will it be updated by sources (either human or machine) other than your program?

Comment: It will be updated once a day by a human for now, later I might automate it

Comment: If all you will be doing is updating the excel sheet. Why bother with python or R? You can achieve the same effect in Excel

Comment: I don't know of any for loop or while loop formula in excel that would do that same, unless you are talking about a macro in VB.net, for which I would say Python or R is much better

Comment: you can do this using formulae alone

Comment: @Usernamenotfound enlighten me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out this way.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('path/file.xls')

row = list(df.index)
for x in row:
    cost = df.loc[x,'Cost']
    price = df.loc[x,'Price']
    Net = cost+5
    df.loc[x,'Lowest_Price'] = 0
    for i in range(Net, price):
        expense = (i*0.15) + 15 #expense formula
        if i - expense >= Net:
            df.loc[x,'Lowest_Price'] = i
            break

#If you want to save it back to an excel file
df.to_excel('path/file.xls',index=False)
```

It gave this output:

```
      Product  Cost  Price  Lowest_Price
0     ABC    32     66          62.0
1     XYZ    15     32           0.0
2     DEF    22     44           0.0
3     JML    60    120          95.0
```

Comment: Cool. Make sure to accept the answer. And go Blue Demons!

Comment: sorry new to Stackoverflow, I just did :) And yes go blue demons!